# Делегирование событий

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть несколько элементов, события на которые нужно обрабатывать похожим образом, как поставить единый обработчик на их общего предка .Т.е При изменении в инпуте должен добавляться класс `.changedInput` только тому инпуту, в котором произошло изменение при этом (самое главное) кнопка с `id="settings-for-device'` привязанная к инпуту должна получать класс `button-press`, если кликнуть повторно - отмена, то получать класс `button-not-press` При этом, остальное инпуты с кнопкаими на страницы без изменений.

исходная разметка

```
<div id="ikz-settings-sets">
 <div id="convert-json-to-html"></div>
```

То что добавляю ...
Проблема в том, что контент с html добавляется через

```
 $('#convert-json-to-html').append( convertJson (..........) );
```

Содержимое с разметкой

```
   function convertJson(......) {

 var str = str +'<input id="' + nameOfKey + key + '"  >' + '</div>' +      
      '<div id="settings-for-device' 
    'class="button-other"></div>';       

                    return str;

                  [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1] }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750

Answer (score 0):

Что то вроде этого

```
$('#convert-json-to-html').on("change", "ваш input",function(){
  $(this).addClass("changedInput");
  $(this).next().toggleClass("button-press button-not-press");
})
```