# Помогите с Динамической Таблицей JAVASCRIPT

Tags: html, jquery, таблицы

Я написала таблицу JS+HTML
Но у меня возникла проблема с добавлением строки.Во время добавления строки дублируется значение первой строки.А мне нужно чтобы каждая строка начиналась пустой.
Что нужно изменить или убрать в коде что бы значение не дублировалось?

И еще может кто-нибудь может подсказать как сделать чтобы таблица по дефолту была сортирована по дате в направлении от самой поздней к более ранней. Чтобы изменить направление
сортировки и поле, пользователь должен кликнуть по заголовку колонки.

Заранее спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="POItablediv">
    <table id="POITable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Start Date</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Spent time</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" /></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" /></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" /></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="+" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(row) {
        var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
    }

    function insRow() {
        var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;
        x.appendChild(new_row);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
C помощью `forEach()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(row) {
        var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
    }

    function insRow() {
        var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;


        new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
            .forEach(function (item) {
                item.value = "";
            });


        x.appendChild(new_row);
    }
</script>
```

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/344278