# Не могу взаимодействовать на jquery с элементом созданным на php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть цикл который создаёт блоки div с данным на php

```
<? foreach ( $arResult['USERS'] as $value ): ?>
    <div class="users_table" value="<?=$value;?>"><?=$value;?></div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Так же есть код на juqery который при клике вытаскивает данные из созданных блоков на php

```
$('.users_table').click( function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Никакой результат не получаю...

Comment: Дивы не поддерживают атрибут value, как мне кажется.

Comment: Правильнее было бы через data-атрибуты что-то кастомное вставлять в див....

Comment: Атрибут `value` может быть использован со следующими элементами: `<button>`, `<input>`, `<meter>`, `<li>`, `<option>`, `<progress>`, `<param>`. [HTML value Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp). Как видите там нет `div`, замените на data-атрибут, как Вам указали выше.

Comment: [Здесь описаны способы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750) добавления обработчиков и использование data-атрибутов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

События к динамически добавленным в DOM элементам можно привязать с помощью `.on`

```
$(document).on('click', '.users_table', function(e){
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Так вы сможете назначить обработчик не на конкретный элемент, а на все элементы с селектором `.users_table`, и не важно были они изначально или их добавили позже.

Comment: Не работает, ещё и элемент в display: none стоит, после определенных действии появляется

Comment: Даже ошибку не выдаёт

Comment: попробуй заменить `alert($(this).val());`  на `alert($(this).attr('value'));`

Comment: Да помогло! Спасибо большое! Ещё вместо document нужно было класс попапа ввести  $('.i_popup_content').on('click', '.users_table', function(e){