# Используйте цикл для задания обработчика для каждого класса

Tags: javascript

Есть 9 классов, каждый со своим id.

```
<div class="hole-game">
    <div class="hole" id="hole1"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole2"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole3"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole4"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole5"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole6"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole7"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole8"></div>
    <div class="hole" id="hole9"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно используя цикл каждому назначить обработчик событий onclick, который вызывает функцию play().
У меня получился примерно такой код, но оно не работает и не могу понять почему.

```
let hole = document.getElementsByClassName("hole");

for(let i = 1; i < 9; i++){
   hole[i] = getHole(i);
   hole[i].onclick = play();
}

function getHole(index){
    return document.getElementById(`hole${index}`)
}
```

Comment: Заголовок вопроса предполагает, что классов несколько, но в представленной Вами разметке класс один - "hole". Есть 9 элементов, но с одним классом. Вы уверены, что предоставленная Вами разметка/описание правильно? Если так, то отредактируйте вопрос для однозначного описания/понимания задачи/проблемы. Помимо этого, имеет смысл рассмотреть вариант с добавлением обработчика контейнеру, а не каждому элементу ([здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750) или [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) более подробно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Неправильно ты, дядя Фёдор, бутерброды ешь...*
Для выборки  по классу и дальнейшей обработки гораздо удобнее будет воспользоваться querySelectorAll() чем getElementsByClassName()

```
let allHole = document.querySelectorAll(".hole");
allHole.forEach(function (el, index) {
    console.log(el, el.id);
});
```

Если же вам неймётся работать с getElementsByClassName() то разбор массива будет выглядеть иначе

```
let allHole = document.getElementsByClassName("hole");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allHole, function(el) {
    console.log(el, el.id);
});
```

Вместо console.log() и развешивайте события.