# Не выполняются некоторые части кода в js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fetch

У меня есть две веб страницы и первая подгружает полностью вторую через fetch запрос.
Вторая веб страница имеет свои селекторы, свой скрипт. Запуск функции с первой веб страницы производится из xhr.onload при получении необходимого результата.
**функция из первой веб-страницы:**

```
window.showBalance = function (wallet, balance1, balance2,wallet2, balance3, balance4){
        $("#choose").html('Ваш кошелёк');
        $("#frame1").css("display","none");
        fetch('./output.html')
        .then(function(response){
            response.text().then(function(text){
            $("#frame-2").html(text);});
            console.log("showBalance");
        });
        $("#wallet-image-balance").css("background-image","url('"+wallet+".png"+"')");
        $("#balance-text-container").html("<div id='balance-text'>"+balance1+"</div><div id='balance-text-dollars'>"+balance2+"</div>");
        $("#balanceContainer").html("<div class='line'></div><div class='balanceContainer'><div class='small' id='sone'></div>"+balance1+"</div><div class='line'></div>");
        $("#sone").css("background-image","url('"+wallet+".png"+"')");
}
```

Также, все элементы изменяемые в этой функции - находились во второй веб-странице и были подгружены через fetch.
В результате, все изменения по этим селекторам не срабатывают.
В чем состоит проблема и есть ли какие-то эффективные методы ее решения?

Comment: для динамических элементов используется делегированная обработка событий

Comment: @Николай но какое событие можно использовать? Я видел как делегированную обработку используют, если обработчик событий не вешается на динамический элемент. Но у меня не совсем такая история, мне нужно изменить элементы по селекторам

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750) (последний пункт в ответе). А лучше переписать вопрос и предоставить МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ код для воспроизведения проблемы. Вы не предоставили то, что Вы подгружаете - это просто HTML-разметка или полноценный HTML-документ?

Comment: **#frame-2** Это случайно не тег `<iframe>`?

Comment: @XelaNimed а если эта функция вызывается в результате срабатывания получения ответа через XHR - какое событие лучше использовать? При том, что это событие происходит до запуска функции, а после этого не подразумеваются какие либо события. Есть ли какое то событие, которое произойдет без каких либо действий для этого? Как "пустое" событие

Comment: @SwaD нет, это тег div

Comment: @XelaNimed дополнил вопрос, но привести код в тривиальном виде довольно проблематично, так как я не до конца понимаю, что необходимо показать. Но это полноценный HTML документ

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то у Вас проблема с доступом по селекторам из первой страницы к подгружаемому HTML-документу. Если это так, то доступ к телу дочернего HTML-документа проблематичен. Если вы имеете возможность модификации серверного кода, то на мой взгляд, лучше при AJAX-запросах отдавать часть документа, а при GET-запросах целиком всю страницу.

Comment: В таких случаях лучше использовать обсервер мутаций