# Как задать команду удаления всего блока #elements при нажатии на картинку .delete

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```
$(function(){
    let a = 1;
    
    $("#add")
        
        .click(function(){
            $("#none").detach()
            $("#spisok").append($("<div>", {"id": "elements" + a }))
            $("#elements" + a).css({
                "width": "470px",
                "min-height": "136px",
                "background-color": "white",
                "margin-bottom": "20px"
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<div>", {"id": "headelements" + a}))
            $("#headelements" + a).css({
                "height": "50px",
            })
            $("#headelements" + a).append($("<div>", {"text": $("#datacase").val(), "id": "nameelements" + a}))
            $("#nameelements" + a).css({
                "padding": "14px 5px 5px 20px",
                "float": "left"
            })
            $("#headelements" + a).append($("<img>", {"src" : "delete.png", "class": "delete i" + a}))
            $(".delete i" + a).css({
                "margin": "20px 0 0 20px",
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<hr>"))
            $("hr").css({
                "margin": "0",
                "border-color": "#f7f7f7"
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<div>", {"id" : "textelements" + a, "text" : $("#datadescription").val()}))
            $("#textelements" + a).css({
                "padding": "10px 5px 5px 20px",
                "color": "gray",
                "word-wrap": "break-word"
            })
            a += 1;
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Там, где вы создаете элемент `.delete`, допишите обработчик клика. Но перед этим сохраните значение `a` и используйте его в обработчике, например так:

```
let b = a; // Обновлено

$("#headelements" + a).append($("<img>", {
    "src" : "delete.png", 
    "class": "delete i" + a,
    "click": function() {
        $(this).closest('#elements' + b).remove();
    }
}))
```

Comment: Переменная a меняется с каждым добавлением блока, и  к моменту удаления кликом определенного блока будет обращаться к другому блоку

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin, Да, упустил мелочь, поправил ответ

Answer (score -2):

Ответов на подобные вопросы уже множество на ruSO и Вам следовало всего лишь немного поискать. Ранее уже [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563020), как добавить подобные обработчики.
Так как пару ответов Вам уже дали, то вставлю и свои 5 копеек. Для тривиальных задач, как Ваша, можно создать обработчик, который будет фильтровать события на родительском контейнере и обрабатывать их. Преимущество в том, что если элементы добавляются динамически/программно, то такой код/подход тоже будет работать. Вам всего лишь необходимо добавить определённый класс и data-свойства с селекторами:

```js
document.onclick = function(docEvent){
  let elem = docEvent.target;
  let isRemover = elem.classList.contains('elements-remover');
  if(isRemover) {
    // Если необходимо предотвратить/отменить событие по умолчанию,
    // то необходимо вызвать метод preventDefault у события
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
    // docEvent.preventDefault();
    // если необходимо также предотвратить дальнейшее "всплытие" события,
    // то необходимо вызвать метод stopPropagation у события
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
    // docEvent.stopPropagation();
    let selector = elem.dataset.removerSelector;
    document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(function (domElem) {
      domElem.remove();
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="must-delete">P#must-delete</p>
<p class="one">P .one</p>
<p class="one">P .one</p>
<p class="two">P .two</p>
<p class="two">P .two</p>
<p>
  <span class="sr">For remove</span>
  <span class="snr">Must not delete</span>
  <span class="sr">For remove</span>
</p>
<p><button class="elements-remover" data-remover-selector="p.one">Remove all P with class .one</button></p>
<p><button class="elements-remover" data-remover-selector="p.two">Remove all P with class .two</button></p>
<p><button class="elements-remover" data-remover-selector="span.sr">Remove all SPAN with class .sr</button></p>
<p><button class="elements-remover" data-remover-selector="#must-delete">Remove elem with id must-delete</button></p>
```

---

Применимо к представленому коду...

```js
document.onclick = function(docEvent){
  let elem = docEvent.target;
  let isRemover = elem.classList.contains('elements-remover');
  if(isRemover) {
    let selector = elem.dataset.removerSelector;
    document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(function (domElem) {
      domElem.remove();
    });
  }
};

$(function(){
    let a = 1;
    $("#add").click(function(){
      $("#spisok").append($("<div>", {"id": "elements" + a }));
      $("#elements" + a).append($("<div>", {"id": "headelements" + a}));
      $("#headelements" + a).append($("<div>", {"text": "bla-bla-bla " + a, "id": "nameelements" + a}));
      $("#headelements" + a).append($("<img>", {
          "src" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp4YCVwpITItdJsn7zLx4PwxbHemX4PYmXG2uRjC=k-s64",
          "class": "delete elements-remover i" + a,
          "title": "Remove bla-bla-bla " + a,
          "data-remover-selector": "#elements" + a
          }));
      a += 1;
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div[id^='elements'] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spisok"></div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Ваш код вообще не имеет отношение к данному вопросу, ему нужен решить как при нажатии на дочерни элемент удалить родительский

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin во-первых, в вопросе автора нет ни слова про родительский элемент. Во-вторых, "удаления всего блока #elements при нажатии на картинку .delete" в заголовке вопроса. В-третьих, используя селекторы нет разницы родительский это элемент или нет, что может сильно экономить время при изменении разметки. Так что Ваш минус неуместен.

Comment: #elements это есть родительский, а .delete - дочерний. Твой пример тут не уместен. Надо помощь человеку его задачу решить а не копипастить от гугла. Может пригодится для другого поста когда ни будь

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin то, что он родительский, не говорит о том, что автор вопроса об этом спрашивал. Я исходил из того, что есть элемент с определённым id по клику на котором необходимо удалить другой элемент. Уместен мой ответ или нет пусть решает автор вопроса и сообшество. Я привёл пример, как сделал бы, чтоб не плодить обработчики и постоянно заморачиваться где и что находиться. С приведённым подходом (когда данные находятся непосредственно в аттрибутах элемента) элементы можно добавлять динамически и хватит одной лишь HTML разметки. И "да" - он пригодится и уже пригождается.

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin если Вы пройдёте по ссылке, то увидете, что я и есть автор "левого кода". Читая вопрос и смотря ответы, пришёл к выводу, что можно решить задачу проще, чем предложили в ответах. Автор вопроса предоставил только сам вопрос в заголовке и код в теле вопроса, так что сложно понять чем ему можно помочь с кодом.

Answer (score -3):

Если идентификатор элемента #elements меняется динамически, то нужно использовать класс вместо идентификатора. Например:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete.i" + a, function(){
    $(this).closest(".elements").remove();
});
```

И нужно добавить класс 'elements' в создаваемый блок, например:

```
$("#spisok").append($("<div>", {"id": "elements" + a, "class": "elements" }))
```

Полностью твой код будет выглятеть так:

```
$(function(){
    let a = 1;
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#none").detach()
            $("#spisok").append($("<div>", {"id": "elements" + a, "class": "elements" }))
            $("#elements" + a).css({
                "width": "470px",
                "min-height": "136px",
                "background-color": "white",
                "margin-bottom": "20px"
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<div>", {"id": "headelements" + a}))
            $("#headelements" + a).css({
                "height": "50px",
            })
            $("#headelements" + a).append($("<div>", {"text": $("#datacase").val(), "id": "nameelements" + a}))
            $("#nameelements" + a).css({
                "padding": "14px 5px 5px 20px",
                "float": "left"
            })
            $("#headelements" + a).append($("<img>", {"src" : "", "class": "delete i" + a}))
            $(".delete i" + a).css({
                "margin": "20px 0 0 20px",
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<hr>"))
            $("hr").css({
                "margin": "0",
                "border-color": "#f7f7f7"
            })
            $("#elements" + a).append($("<div>", {"id" : "textelements" + a, "text" : $("#datadescription").val()}))
            $("#textelements" + a).css({
                "padding": "10px 5px 5px 20px",
                "color": "gray",
                "word-wrap": "break-word"
            })
            
            $(document).on("click", ".delete.i" + a, function(){
                $(this).closest(".elements").remove();
            });
            a += 1;
    });
```

Еще возможно, что стоит убедиться, что ваш скрипт Jquery подключен к странице и что вы используете последнюю версию Jquery.

Comment: Не сработало. При нажатии ничего не происходит(((

Comment: Отредактировал код

Comment: Ничего не понял, но все заработало! Спасибо большое)))