# Почему после подгрузки (ajax) постов не работает обработчик событий?

Tags: javascript, ajax, события, javascript-events

на странице есть посты, при нажатии на один из них срабатывает обработчик. при нажатии на кнопку аяксом подгружаются новые посты, но обработчик для них уже не работает. установил обработчик делегированием в расчете на то что такой проблемы не будет. в чем здесь ошибка?

так выглядят посты при загрузке страницы:

```
<div class="items row  flexbox c_3 ">
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

а так после загрузке новых постов:

```
<div class="items row  flexbox c_3 ">
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="news-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12--500 ">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="detail-news hiden">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

а так выглядит обработчик:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    detailNews = document.querySelectorAll('.lookbook .items .detail-news'),
        newsWrapper = document.querySelector('.items '),
        newsItems = document.querySelectorAll('.news-item span');
    let showMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.more_text_ajax');

    function hideDetail() {
        detailNews.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add('hiden');
        })
    }

    function showDetail(i) {
        detailNews[i].classList.remove('hiden');
    }

    hideDetail();

    function showCurrentNews(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let target = e.target;

        newsItems.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (target === item) {
                hideDetail();
                showDetail(i);
            }
        })
    }

    newsWrapper.addEventListener('click', showCurrentNews);
})
```

Comment: Ты не верно реализовал делегирование... Хоть обработчик и навешивается на родителя, но сами функции используют "старые выборки" элементов. Все "выборки элементов" должны делаться внутри функции обработчика. Так же при такой организации функций делегирование не будет работать. Все функции так же нужно перенести в функцию обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо! все работает.

Comment: @ksa  либо использовать живые коллекции

Comment: Либо [фильтровать события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750) контейнера на основе целевого элемента...