# Как обратиться к ID элемента через функцию-шаблон по 'onclick' на другом элементе?

Tags: javascript

В данном примере есть два дива, стоящих рядом. Как по клику на одном диве поменять свойства второго? Явным образом указывать ID нельзя, т.к. таких объектов много.
Я подумал, что как бы легче указывать ID в атрибуте "onclick" - в условиях функции, чем копировать эту функцию много раз или писать массив.

```js
function funcOne(x) {
  document.getElementById(`"${x}"`).style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.part {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="part-1" class="part">1</div>
  <div id="part-2" class="part" onclick="funcOne(part-1)">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не используйте обработчики событий в атрибутах элементов и, исходя из Ваших комментариев к принятому ответу, не полагайтесь на порядок/структуру элементов в документе, т.к. это вызовет проблемы при изменении разметки. Почему нельзя использовать id (даже если их много)? Id как раз и используется для быстрого обращения к элементу.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! 
А вы считаете, что код в атрибутах "oninput", "onclick" - это небезопасно? То есть, вообще вставлять этот атрибут опасно?
Согласен полностью, что так делать плохо именно из-за возможного изменения структуры! Но я делаю для себя, надо как скорее! Потом исправлю :)

Comment: Это неудобно и смешивает разметку с кодом/поведением. Представьте, что у Вас 100500 элементов и Вам нужно что-то изменить. Другой вариант - это совместная работа программистов и дизайнеров, где последним все эти методы и их параметры не интересны или не понятны. Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563022/182750) пример фильтрации событий контейнера, это более развёрнуто объяснит, что я имею ввиду. **P.S.:** *если можно сделать сразу "по-человечески", то так и нужно делать, а тем более для себя.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я подумал, что **как бы легче указывать ID в атрибуте "onclick"** - в условиях функции

там есть `this`

```html
<input id='a'
onfocus='console.log(this.id + " in focus")'
onblur='console.log(this.id + " blured")'
>

<input id='b'
onfocus='console.log(this.id + " in focus")'
onblur='console.log(this.id + " blured")'
>

<input id='c'
onfocus='console.log(this.id + " in focus")'
onblur='console.log(this.id + " blured")'
```

в нём есть ссылка на родительский объект, а оттуда уже и на всех "своих" ровесников можно глянуть. `this.parentElement.childNodes` как то так...

> Я хочу, чтоб когда щелкнули по текстэреа, включился чекед на чекбоксе.

> чтоб сама функция брала ID из onclick как-то, потому что не всегда они рядом стоят

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='w'>
<label for='w'>
<textarea>
как на счет этого?
</textarea>
</label><br>

<input type='checkbox' id='x'>
<label for='x' contenteditable='true'>
или этого?
</label><br>

<div>ладно, ладно... я серьёзен)</div>
<q>Явным образом указывать ID нельзя, т.к. таких объектов много.</q>
<form>
хм...
<input type='checkbox' id='y' value='0'><br>
<textarea onclick='this.parentElement.children[0].checked="true";'>
оно ведь?)
</textarea>
</form>

<form>
<input type='checkbox' id='z' value='0'><br>
<textarea onfocus='this.parentElement.children[0].checked=true;'
onblur='this.parentElement.children[0].checked=false;'>
я даже немного наванговать могу до такого варианта...
</textarea>
</form>
```

но это ведь все равно не то чего хотелось, верно? дык может все таки сформулируете задачу по полнее? :3

---

### UPD 4.01.2024 / 18:29

`чтоб в textarea был текст пользователя ... А как только он удаляет текст - чекед пропадал бы`

```html
<form>
<input type='checkbox'>
<textarea
  oninput='this.parentElement.children[0].checked = (this.value!="" ? true : false)'>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Парни, спасибо вам большое! Думаю, надо все-таки двигаться в сторону previousElementSibing, короче, привязываться к тому, что в большинстве случаев они рядом стоят. Подумаю сейчас, приму один из вариантов, я еще начинающий пи@#ик

Comment: Нет, в третьем случае не угадали, там название чекбокса типа "другое:" - и в текстэреа перечисление что именно

Comment: Хотя да, кстати! Ведь он может нажать на текстовое поле, и ничего не написать там! Ну и фиг с ним, сам виноват, типа? :)

Comment: @Игорь00073 `название чекбокса не угадали` я как бы и не пытался... так значит мы играем в угадайку? ну всм в "аналитическое составление ТЗ"? океееей :3 `сам виноват, типа?` #W и #X если что просто рофлы) в остальных, эм... виноват? у меня не настолько крепкая кофейная гуща, чтоб без примера кода и уточнений понять, что вы щас имеете ввиду

Comment: Забейте, это я так, сам с собой. Я сейчас посмотрю, может вообще только sass-ом обойдусь? Хотя нет, мне же нужно чтоб в textarea был текст пользователя, чтоб условие соблюлось и чекд загорелся сверху. А как только он удаляет текст - чекед пропадал бы. Скорее всего, ваш вариант ближе к этому. Остальное сам допилю, вы и так очень помогли!

Comment: @Игорь00073, добавил в ответ вариант посвежее. p.s. можно конечно и на `onChange` сделать, но он срабатывает только при потере полем фокуса(клик мимо поля)

Comment: Спасибо! 
Получилось сделать только как у вас написано, прямо в html. А как только я убираю в функцию, this пропадает. Вместо него - объект window.  Никак не получилось. Если у вас будет возможность, объясните плиз,  как сделать, чтоб this не пропадала в функции по onclick или в данном случае, по oninput

Comment: @Игорь00073, ну дык... `this` это ссылка на объект того html тега, в атрибуте которого код исполняется. чтобы в коде сделать "тоже самое" нужно хотя бы объект этого тега получить(вместо `this` пишите что то вроде `document.getElementById("id_of_textarea")`) и уже на него вешаете ивент. разумеется можно выбрать нужный объект тега и любым другим образом - `document.QuerySelector("#id_of_textarea")` например. или если элементов много `document.QuerySelectorAll("textarea")` а дальше к полученному массиву вешаем события например циклом(на каждый отдельно).

Comment: @Игорь00073 впрочем... можно все нужные чекбоксы и текстареа обернуть в форму, тогда теоретически будет достаточно повесить событие только на неё. правда не уверен можно ли в таком случае получить ид именно поля стригиревшего onInput, а не всей формы... повесьте на форму `oninput="console.log(this)"`, потеребите любой ареа, а после щупайте прилетевший в консоль объект, может что то да найдется. p.s. инпуты не обязательно именно пихать внутрь формы, можно и привязать атрибутом: https://webref.ru/html/input/form хотя не уверен сработает ли так... вроде js атрибутную связь не видит...

Comment: Спасибо! Ну, в общем, я так оставил, потому что из html удобно ссылаться на чекбоксы, которые раскиданы по-разному, и одним правилом в них не попадешь. Они не рядом с инпутом (между ними разные спаны, текст иногда...) и не на одинаковом расстоянии от начала. Но прочитал, что вроде как-то избавляются от пропадания this с помощью замыкания или "bind", но я не допер. А вообще завлекательно было бы! По поводу привязки к Form - надо будет попробовать как-нибудь!

Comment: Но в любом случае - да! весь затык в том, что нужно объект, в котором this произошел, описать явно, а тот факт, что в нем произошло событие, не катит...

Comment: Я теперь с валидацией бьюсь! Это вообще треш!
Не хочу брать библиотеку потому что там оформление сделать трудно хорошее, и мне нужны алерты на всех инпутах, а не только на первом с ошибкой! Сделал, но целый день опять просидел... Там проблема была, что как только функция находила первый же заполненный инпут - она пропускала, а мне надо было, чтобы пока все не заполнятся, она не пропускала...